# Opening same window while using noreferrer

Tags: html

Without `noreferrer` the target opens the link in the same tab if it has already opened.

```
<a target="google" href="https://www.google.com" rel="noreferrer">Open</a>
```

While setting `rel="noreferrer"` attribute on `<a>` as above will always open new tab.

Is there any way to use same tab(but not current) with `noreferrer` everytime link clicked?

Comment: Have you tried without setting target? Why are you using target?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the **target** attribute then use the **parent** value like this `target="_parent"` for it to open in the same tab.

```
<a target="_parent" href="https://www.google.com" rel="noreferrer">Open</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Opening link in a new window not related to `rel="noreferrer"` attribute.
It related to `target` attribute.
Use this attribute with `_self` value.

```html
<a target="_self" href="https://www.google.com" rel="noreferrer">Open</a>
```

**Note:** the target value is `_self` as default. You can just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a target="_self" href="https://www.google.com" rel="noreferrer">Open</a>
```